# Microsoft Graph Get Calendars of All Users

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-calendar, outlook-api

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph API to get the calendars of all the users in an organization. Is there a way for an admin with the appropriate permissions can get all user calendars with one request to the API? I'm aware that it is possible by first retrieving a list of all the users then using the user IDs to send a request for each's calendars. I'd like to avoid this approach so that I can avoid making too many calls to the API. I'd also like to be able to do this without every using having to share their calendars with the admin. Does support for something like this exist? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to get all Calendars of all users in one request.

You can do it only over the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

There are two part to your question:
1: Get all calendars of all users in call: This is not possible. 
2: Get access to calendars with users explicitly sharing the calendars. This is possible using app-only access tokens.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service